# How to access webcams with JMF?

Tags: java, webcam, jmf

I would like to access my webcam with JMF, create a snapshot, and email it. I have working email code, but every time I try:

```
CaptureDeviceInfo inf = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice("vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture(Win32):0");
        player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(inf.getLocator());
```

But I get a `nullpointexception` error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code is not detecting the webcam

you must copy the jmf.properties file to the same directory as your executable jar

you will find the jmf.properties file int the lib folder of your jmf installation.

For me it was C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e\lib\jmf.properties

Answer (score 0):

the device name is "Microsoft WDM Image Capture", what you pass to CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(). the "vfw://0" part is the locator.

see Owen McGovern's example: http://geoffair.net/java/java_sun1.htm. It has working player *and* working snapshot code.

Comment: did you find any solution for this ? for me i am not getting any device when i call CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);