# Cannot find a Player for :vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0

Tags: java, webcam, jmf

I'm trying to get a picture with your webcam, but I get an error:

> javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :vfw:Microsoft
>   WDM Image Capture (Win32):0

I have a simple standard code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    Player player;

    Main() {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try{
                    player.stop();
                    player.deallocate();
                    player.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){}
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        setSize(640, 480);
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        String mediaFile = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
        try {
            MediaLocator mlr = new MediaLocator(mediaFile);
            player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mlr);
            player.setRate(100);
            if (player.getVisualComponent() != null) {
                panel.add("Center", player.getVisualComponent());
            }
            if (player.getControlPanelComponent() != null) {
                panel.add("South", player.getControlPanelComponent());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got exception " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've already checked JMF Registry, camera match, it is not in doubt:

> Name = vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0
>
> Locator = vfw://0

And the JMStudio is also working normally and displays video

I also read this page about **jmf.propertis** and placed the file in the **root** of the project in Eclipse, as well as in the root **src**

> [Accessing webcams with JMF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313911/accessing-webcams-with-jmf)

And now I have no idea why it can not work?

Answer (score 0):

1. need to set java path to 32bit jdk in windows environment variables.
2. then use JMF to to capture device
3. add proper JMF jar to project
4. Run the project.

It worked for me.